# Why does iterating through a map fail in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, iteration

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
map<wstring,int>::iterator it;
map<wstring,int> bimap;

//Creating Bigrams out of monograms
for (it= container.begin(); it != container.end();)
{
    bimap[it->first + L" "+((++it)->first)]++;
    ++it;
    ++it;
}
```

If I run this code the program crashes and the reason for that crash is the second increment of iterator `it`. Why is it like this? The iterator needs to increment and I am incrementing it twice instead of once! What's wrong with it?

If I want to save two adjacent map item values into some other maps like I am actually doing in the above for statement, how should I go about it? What if I want to combine and store every 3 other items together?

I need to update the iterator to go on respectively, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I am lost in your `++` jungle....how about yourself?

Comment: actually the first ++ is going to increment the number of each values occurrences. those two other it++ are actually for going to the next pair of values . (suppose its it+=2 )

Answer (score 2):

You set your loop to end when you reach the `container.end`, but because you increment the iterator *twice* you reach the end, then with that second it++ you try to go further (error).

Example: let's say you have 3 elements.

```
it = container.begin()

++it // ok
++it //ok

it != container.end() //true

++it // ok BUT AT THIS MOMENT it = container.end !
++it // CRASH
```

Comment: Then how should i go about it and achieve what i want? i need to get two adjacent value and save them into another map, and move to the other two ( 3 and 4 and go on to 5 and 6 and etc! ) i cant think of any other means of doing it! :-/

Comment: But what if there is an odd number of values?

Comment: I can get around that, by getting the maps length , what i cant do now is freely iterate through a map from any where of it! being linear like this is\nt good at all :(

Comment: Hm, i just noticed you also increment it in the dereference operator [] therefore you increment `it` even 3 times, instead of 2. This is all very risky. How about creating second iterator which will be 'the safety one' and one element after the first one?

Comment: assume there is only 1 element and even first example will result in SIGSEGV

Answer (score 2):

just increment once on each iteration, and use an auxiliary counter modulo 3 (reset it after each 3 iterations) and do the task you want to do every time it is 0. something like:

```
int counter_mod3;
for (it= container.begin(); it != container.end();)
{
  if(counter_mod3 == 0) // This zero chooses the phase on which the "sampling" is to be made
    bimap[it->first + L" "+(it->first)]++;  //increment!

  ++it;  //increment!
  counter_mod3 = (counter_mod3++) % 3;
}
```

If you want to start on other element, instead of the first, just change the phase to 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

you are incrementing your iterator several times

```
for (it= container.begin(); it != container.end();)
{
    bimap[it->first + L" "+((++it)->first)]++;  //increment!
    ++it;  //increment!
    ++it;  //increment!
}
```

so you night be at the last element, enter the loop because `it != container.end()` condition is met and then go out of bounds.

if you know you will do 2 increments always, but end if there is only one element left, then you might consider this:

```
for (it= container.begin(); it != container.end();)
{
    //do something
    ++it;  //increment!

    if(it!=container.end()){  //check again. can we move forward?
    //do something
    ++it;  //increment!
    }
}
```